# QGIS Georeferencer tool not keeping inserted coordinate values

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-2.8, qgis-2.10

I'm currently giving a basic training course on QGIS and, on the last class, one of the students stumbled upon a problem I wasn't able to solve - nor can I find a reason for it.

We are using QGIS 2.10.1.

I was showing them how to use the Georeferencer and, whenever she introduces a control point and types in the corresponding coordinate, nothing happens in the GCP table - i.e., she adds the new control point, types in the coordinate, but the table fields "Dest. X" and "Dest. Y" remain with "0", no matter what we try. We also tried to edit those fields directly in the table, but they do not change their value.

I also attempted to install Qgis 2.8 on her machine, to see if that could be a solution, but the Georeferencer showed the same behavior.

She used exactly the same installer as the other students in class (and myself) and she was the only one with this problem. All computers in class are running Windows (mostly 8 and 8.1, but I think there is one machine running on Win 7, not sure right now) and from what I can recall, all the machines are 64-bit.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?